# Validating if atleast one checkbox is checked or one input field is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need better validation logic, where some Checkboxes and some input fields are grouped together.

The user either have to check at least one checkbox or have to fill at least one input box.

If a checkbox is checked or an input field is filled then the complete group is validated.

What will be the best possible way to validate such a situation?

e.g

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check-deal" value="1" grouped="deal" >
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check-deal" value="2" grouped="deal">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check-deal" value="3" grouped="deal">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check-deal" value="4" grouped="deal">

<input class="input-group" type="text" name="deal-name1" value="" grouped="deal">
<input class="input-group" type="text" name="deal-name2" value="" grouped="deal">
```

I have defined an extra attribute `grouped` for all input and checkboxes that should be grouped togather

but getting no idea how to validate the group as best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to take count of each validations. And then check if any of the two has count greater than 0 or not. Guruprasad's answer won't work if you enter text on second textbox because it won't filter all the textboxes. You have to use filter function for this :

```
$("input[type='text'],textarea").filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() != "";
}).length;
```

Here's a jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/myfLgpdv/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/61nd3wnw/)**

**Point No.1** : There isn't any attribute called `grouped` for `html` as of my knowledge but I would suggest you to use `data-*` prefixed attribute names like `data-grouped` or `data-anyname` which is **valid**

**Point No.2** : I rather categorized your `checkboxes` and `textboxes` into separate `div`s and below is how it is:

```
<div class="chkbox">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check-deal" value="1" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check-deal" value="2" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check-deal" value="3" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check-deal" value="4" />
</div>
<div class="txtbxs">
    <input class="input-group" type="text" name="deal-name1" value="" />
    <input class="input-group" type="text" name="deal-name2" value="" />
</div>
<button class="btnValidate">Validate</button>
```

**Point No.3** : Below is how you can validate using `jquery`

```
$('.btnValidate').on('click',function(){
    var chkLength=$('.chkbox .checkbox:checked').length; //get checkbox checked length
    var filledText=$(".txtbxs .input-group").val()!=""; 
    //get bool value whether any of the text box is filled or not
    if(chkLength || filledText) //check with or condition
        alert('valid')
    else
        alert('invalid');
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/61nd3wnw/1/)**

As @AkshatG pointed in his answer the discrepancy was there in my answer so I've edited it and here is the updated solution.

```
$('.btnValidate').on('click',function(){
    var chkLength=$('.chkbox .checkbox:checked').length;
    var filledText=false; //First set it to false
    $.each($(".txtbxs .input-group"),function(index,value){
        if($(value).val()!="")
        {
            filledText=true//if it finds any value then set it to true
            return;//break from $.each
        }
    })
    if(chkLength || filledText) 
        alert('valid')
    else
        alert('invalid');
});
```